# One foreign key in one table for 2 different fields

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, foreign-keys

Is there a way for me to create only one foreign key in one table that refers to 2 different fields in that same table

example:
table: family

ID | bird | bird_mom | bird_dad

1_**__*X*__*_*__***2****_*__*_*__**_3

2_***_*__***A****_*___***4****_*__*_*___**_5

3____B

4____M

5____N

ID is primary and autoincrement and also foreign key for "bird_mom" and "bird_dad" field. 
So when I change entries X,A,B,M,N I dont need to change it everywhere, but it will always be recognized by foreign key-ID

Comment: You can just add two foreign keys. One on bird_mom and one on bird_dad, both referencing ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, "[foreign key](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)" is the name for the child field that points to the parent, so you would have *two* foreign keys:

```sql
CREATE TABLE family (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    bird TEXT,
    bird_mom INTEGER REFERENCES family(ID),
    bird_dad INTEGER REFERENCES family(ID)
)
```

Comment: Thank you.
So when I want to access bird_mom I should use ID.bird_mom right?

Comment: There is no table named `ID`. If you have a new question, please ask it as a question. (But I'd guess you should look up "self join" first.)